# Creating a new file with a different extention

Tags: c, string, file

In my project I have one file as input, and I need the output file with a new extension. Suppose my input file is `file.txt` here as `name`. I need output file as `file.dic`. I tried the following.

```
fpout = fopen(strcat(name,".dic"), WRITE_ONLY);
```

I know it's not the correct way. But what should I do to get the file name as `file.dic`?

Comment: Your parens are unbalanced.

Comment: "Obviously", you have to replace 'txt' with 'dic'. It's just standard string stuff, so what's the problem?

Comment: What else you would expect when concatenating `"file.txt"` with `".dic"` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
 char * newstr;
  newstr = strstr (name,"txt");// name = "file.txt"
  strncpy (newstr,"dic",3);
  //newstr = file.dic
```

this will replace the `file.txt` with `file.dic`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the file extension, this is an easy way to do it.

```
int lenght; 

lenght = strlen(name);

name[lenght - 1] = c;
name[lenght - 2] = i;
name[lenght - 3] = d;
name[lenght - 4] = .;
```

you can also use `while`, and while you don't check a '.' increment i, then change the extension in the same way.

or

```
  strncpy (strstr (name,"txt"),"dic",3);
```

Comment: This might not work for two reasons. First off, the name can be in a read-only part of the OP's code (when declared as an immediate). Secondly, your code will remove the terminating zero from a C-string, and that is usually fatal.

Comment: it won't remove the terminating zero. Strlen don't give the lenght + 1 i think, no ?

Comment: Array indices start at 0. In C and C++, accessing `array[sizeOfArray]` is out of bounds. In case of a string `string[lengthOfString]` refers to the terminator. The code might also produce unexpexted results if the input filename suddenly has a different extension, or none at all.

Comment: Yeah but he asked for this exemple, i don't thinks he is professional programmer, he just asked about something he didn't know and he wants to understand. I know gice code is not a good thing but i think in this case it was the thing to do.